# Unable to connect codeigniter4 with sqlite3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How can i connect sqlite3 with ci4?
my configurations are:

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'edmis.db',
    'DBDriver' => 'SQLite3',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

file **edmis.db** exist in folder `'writable'`

Error i am receiving.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste the text of your error.  [Why you should not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  Is it only the migration failing, eg does the app work otherwise?

Comment: yes it is connecting with database and creating table when i run migration from browser/php code

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you uncommented these lines in php.ini:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```